# How to connect to Azure Mongo Db?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I have nodeJs application which I try to connect with Azure Mongo Db. My connection looks like this:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

const getDb = async() => {
  const dbName = process.env.MONGO_NAME; //taken from Azure Cosmo DB => Connection String => USERNAME
  const url = process.env.MONGO_URL; //PRIMARY CONNECTION STRING
  const client = new MongoClient(url);
  await client.connect();
  return client.db(dbName);
}
```

It perfectly works with local environment (local mongo from container). But when I deploy it as docker container, I can't fetch any data.
I checked logs and it doesn't throw any errors. The object "client" looks normal, but it doesn't response anything after:

```
const db = await getDb();
const collection = db.collection('myCollectionName');
```

How can I connect to db or at least debug this problem?

Comment: what is the error you see?

Comment: @Sajeetharan There is no error... It is a main problem.

Comment: There should be some error, which operation fails?

Comment: @Sajeetharan db.collection('myCollectionName') responses nothing. Without any error. Looks like db is empty, but it is not true. I see proper collections in data explorer.

Comment: are you connecting to the same database from the local as well?

Comment: @Sajeetharan from local I connect to a replica of this db.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the values of your `MONGO_NAME` and `MONGO_URL` (of course, obfuscate the instance name and part of the key in the connection string). It's unclear, as written. Also, it's unclear what symptoms you're seeing (based on what you provided).